# Obtener nombre de usuario en C++

Tags: c++, ubuntu, bash

Lo que estoy intentando concretamente es obtener el nombre de usuario y guardarlo en un char, ya que con getlogin(),cuserid y logname, devuelven array y no me deja guardarlo en un char, estoy programando en c++.

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar qué es lo que llevas hecho en tu código? Para que te podamos ayudar sobre eso

Comment: El tipo `char` guarda un solo carácter, pero el nombre de usuario será típicamente una secuencia de caracteres (una cadena, o _string_). En C las cadenas se implementan como arrays de caracteres con un terminador nulo, y el programa accede a ellas a través de punteros a `char`. La función `getlogin()` que mencionas retorna precisamente eso, un puntero a `char`. ¿Podrías mostrar qué código estás intentando que "no te deja"?

Comment: `void crearhistorial(){     char *usuario[];
usuario=getlogin();
ofstream fichero; fichero.open("/home/usuario/Escritorio/historial",ios::app);
fichero.close();
}`

Lo que intento hacer es que el fichero se cree siempre en el escritorio del usuario que inicie sesión en el ordenador,para eso,intento poner la ruta del fichero siempre en el historial,pero eso siempre dependerá de quien sea el usuario

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que intentas hacer en C++ sería algo así:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    try
    {
            std::string name = std::string(getlogin());
            std::ofstream f("/tmp/" + name + "/log.txt");
            f << "Lo que quieras guardar " << std::endl;
            f.close();
            return 0;
    }
    catch(std::exception e)
    {
      std::cout << "Error en getlogin()" << std::endl;
      return 1;
    }
}
```